# Make a command that maps arguments in a message after certain words

Tags: discord.js

I want to make it so that it would grab out certain information after certain words, and stop at certain words, for example

`ss!submit | WIYISD: _____ | SHIWW: _____ | WDYWTA: _____ | SPN: _____`
Collect arguements after the WIYISD:, SHIWW:, WDYWTA:, and SPN: and stop at the |'s after collecting each arguement.

I just don't know where to start.

I looked at what other people did, and I tried to pull it off myself but can't figure out how.

Edit: I'd like it based off of user input, and posts it in a channel, kind of similar to the bug-bot in discord testers.

Answer (score 1):

Start by splitting at the vertical bars to get each portion of the string ([`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)). Then, iterate through the substrings (["Loops and iteration"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)) and check the start of each ([`String.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)), dealing with the resulting arguments however you want.

```js
const str = 'ss!submit | WIYISD: hopefully | SHIWW: this code | WDYWTA: will | SPN: help you!';

const split = str.split(' | ').slice(1); // Also removing the command portion.

const args = {};

for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  const arg = split[i];
  
  if (arg.startsWith('WIYISD: ')) args.WIYISD = arg.replace('WIYISD: ', '');
  else if (arg.startsWith('SHIWW: ')) args.SHIWW = arg.replace('SHIWW: ', '');
  else if (arg.startsWith('WDYWTA: ')) args.WDYWTA = arg.replace('WDYWTA: ', '');
  else if (arg.startsWith('SPN: ')) args.SPN = arg.replace('SPN: ', '');
  else {
    console.error('Check your syntax.'); // Send an error message instead...
    break; // ...and return (illegal in this context).
  }
}

console.log(args); // The result in this example is an object, not an array.
```

Incorporating this into your message event...

```js
// const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = 'ss!';

bot.on('message', message => {
  // Stop if the author is a bot or the message doesn't start with the prefix.
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  // This is a very crude setup. Consider a command handler to keep the code organized.
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}submit `)) {
    const split = message.content.split(' | ').slice(1);

    const args = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      const arg = split[i];

      if (arg.startsWith('WIYISD: ')) args.WIYISD = arg.replace('WIYISD: ', '');
      else if (arg.startsWith('SHIWW: ')) args.SHIWW = arg.replace('SHIWW: ', '');
      else if (arg.startsWith('WDYWTA: ')) args.WDYWTA = arg.replace('WDYWTA: ', '');
      else if (arg.startsWith('SPN: ')) args.SPN = arg.replace('SPN: ', '');
      else {
        return message.channel.send(':x: Invalid syntax.')
          .catch(console.error); // Make sure the catch rejected promises.
      }
    }

    // Use 'args' as you wish.
  }
});
```

Comment: how do I make it so the users can customize what they put in there, would it be looking in between the |'s and making sure they have the correct syntax / making sure it's not empty?

Comment: If you mean how to use this for a user's message, in your client's [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) event, using [`Message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) instead of a pre-defined string would produce the desired result.

Comment: as in
`bot.on("ready", (message.content) => {code})`
or
`bot.on("message.content", (message) => {code})`
or something different?

Comment: `bot.on('message', message => {...});`, then access the message's content with `message.content`.

Comment: I put   `var str = ``${message.content}``;` do I need to put ss!submit before the `${message.content}? And what happens if I turn the `console.log(args)` into `message.reply(args)`

Comment: I tried the example code, and with the `message.reply(`@username `${args}``)` and it gave me [object Object] but with `console.log(args)` it works completely fine. I might find another stack overflow report on how to get console messages into a discord.js message